# How to import class from a different folder in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, import, package

I have the following project structure:

```
root_folder
│
├── folder_1
│   │
│   ├── main.py
│   │
│   └── url.py
│
└── folder_2
    │
    └── main.py
```

The file `url.py` contains the class URL.

In the file `folder_2\main.py` I would like to instantiate an object of type URL.

**Can anyone give me some suggestions?**

I have already tried several imports

```
from folder_1.url import URL

from .folder_1.url import URL

from ..folder_1.url import URL


ecc...
```

but so far none have worked.

Comment: Don't think of things being imported from *folders*; you import from *packages*, so the real question is how to use a folder to define a package.

Comment: How you import `url` is going to depend on how you execute `main.py`, and the answer will also change depending on whether `main.py` is being executed as a script or used as a module itself.

Comment: You also need to be aware of where `import` is looking for the module. See[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/where-does-python-look-for-modules/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 1):

`from folder_1.url import URL` This should work; check your spelling in your code. And also, you can read the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder). I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily just like this:

[image]
don't forget to set exact path to your python file. If the program gives an error it means you didn't set path correctly.

If they are in same directory you can directly import these files if they are not you should edit the directory like `from path/settings import *`
and to use this files classes and functions you can call them directly like this:(Lets say there is movement function inside Player class)

```
Player().movement()
```